# PHP XML Array hell

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I'm trying to get an XML array's data.
Here's the data I have going in:

```
[MyCallResult] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [errorMessage] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [arrayAvailableField] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [MyCall.output.AvailableField] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [fieldName] => orderno
                                [fieldValue] => 10314451
                                [sequenceNumber] => 1
                            )

                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [fieldName] => ordersuf
                                [fieldValue] => 00
                                [sequenceNumber] => 2
                            )

                        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [fieldName] => custno
                                [fieldValue] => 16137
                                [sequenceNumber] => 3
```

And this goes on for another 30+ fields.
What I want to do is go thru a loop and pick off what I need with something like an IF statement (if $node->fieldname = "orderno" then $orderno = $node->fieldValue)

I can do a foreach loop and get all the values, but I can't seem to get an if statement to keep things going (like the if finds a match and jumps out of the loop).

Here's something I tried:

```
    foreach ($xml->MyCall->arrayAvailableField-> "MyCall.output.AvailableField"} as $node) {
    if ($node['fieldName'] = "orderno") {
        $ordno = $node->fieldValue;
    } elseif ($node['fieldname'] = "ordersuf") {
        $ordersuf = $node->fieldValue;
    }
    }
```

At least I got the first orderno - but the rest failed.

I'm fairly new at PHP, so I'm sure I'm heading down a wrong path - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: double check your equal sign usage... eg `$node['fieldName'] = "orderno"` should be `$node['fieldName'] == "orderno"` this might be a simple typo :)

Comment: Hi, in questions like this, it's best to provide a [mcve] - that is, a small piece of code in the question itself that we can copy and paste to reproduce the problem ourselves. In the case of XML, rather than showing `print_r` or `var_dump` output, include a small section of the XML itself; it's then easier for someone else to play around with different ways of accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I found an answer - might not be elegant, but it's working.
Here's what I got:

```
$x = $xml->xpath("//MyCall.output.AvailableField");

for ($y = 0; $y <= count($x)-1; $y++) {
switch (trim($x[(int)$y]->fieldName)) {
    case "orderno": $orderno = $x[(int)$y]->fieldValue; break;
    case "ordersuf": $ordersuf = $x[(int)$y]->fieldValue; break;
    case "custno": $custno = $x[(int)$y]->fieldValue; break;
```

I'm getting data, so happy camper.
Thanks again to all who helped :)

Comment: Like I said - new at this site :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likley the typo around the single equals sign

```
if ($node['fieldName'] = "orderno") {
    $ordno = $node->fieldValue;
} elseif ($node['fieldname'] = "ordersuf") {
    $ordersuf = $node->fieldValue;
}
```

Change it to use double equals:

```
if ($node['fieldName'] == "orderno") {
    $ordno = $node->fieldValue;
} elseif ($node['fieldname'] == "ordersuf") {
    $ordersuf = $node->fieldValue;
}
```

your first "if" is always *true* otherwse